# Spring and Hibernate 4: get is not valid without active transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-transactions, spring-annotations

I am using Spring annotations and hibernate to create a DAO.  I am using Spring 3.2.5 and hibernate 4.3.3.  For some reason I keep getting this exception:

org.hibernate.HibernateException: get is not valid without active transaction

Here is the relevant portion of my spring app context:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

        <!-- Pick up the HibernateHouseDAO spring bean -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="jinvestor.jhouse.download" />

        <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="annotatedClasses">
                <list>
                    <value>jinvestor.jhouse.core.HouseEntity</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
<!--                    <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop> -->
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${dataSource.driver}" />
            <property name="url" value="${dataSource.url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${dataSource.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${dataSource.password}" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </bean>
```

This is my DAO:

```
@Repository("dao")
@Profile("mysql")
@Transactional
public class HibernateHouseDAO implements HouseDAO {

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public HibernateHouseDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public House load(long id) {

        // this throws a nosuch method error for openSession.
//      Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, false);

        // this throws an error on the lack of a transaction.
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        HouseEntity entity = (HouseEntity) session.get(HouseEntity.class, id);
        return House.fromEntity(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(House house) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(new HouseEntity(house));
    }
```

BTW the @Transactional is spring's, not javax.transaction.  Here is my unit test:

```
// MT stands for manual test
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/applicationContext.xml"})
@ActiveProfiles(profiles={"test","mysql"})
public class HibernateHouseDAOMT extends HouseDAOTest {

    @Autowired
    private HouseDAO dao;

    @Override
    public HouseDAO getDao() {
        return dao;
    }
}
```

Here is my SQL schema in case you need to know it:

```
create table homes (zpid BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, address VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,squareFeet INT UNSIGNED,soldPrice INT UNSIGNED, latitude INT,longitude INT,lastSoldDate DATE, yearBuilt YEAR,acres FLOAT UNSIGNED,beds TINYINT UNSIGNED,baths TINYINT UNSIGNED, INDEX (address)) ENGINE = 'INNODB';
```

Also, all of my code is on github in case you want to see something I did not copy here.  This is the project root on github:

https://github.com/msknapp/JInvestor/tree/master/JHouse/jhouse.download

Please help me get this to work.

===================
Update:

Switching to Hibernate Transaction Manager:

```
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

and here is the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getConnectionProvider()Lorg/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/ConnectionProvider;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getConnectionProvider()Lorg/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/ConnectionProvider;
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.getDataSource(SessionFactoryUtils.java:90)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateTransactionManager.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    ... 40 more
```

based on this, maybe I am missing a dependency in my pom, or have a bad dependency.  I will try to find out...

I am using mysql-connector-java version 5.1.29, perhaps that is incompatible?

Comment: You should use a HibernateTransactionManager instead of a DataSourceTransactionManager.

Comment: I tried that before, the app context fails to load.  It doesn't even tell me why.

Comment: If it fails to load, then you should have a stack trace in the logs. Use a HibernateTransactionManager, edit your question to show your updated code, and post the stack trace of the exception you get.

Comment: @msknapp In the HibernateTransactionManager, did you injected the datasource or the session factory. You need the session factory.

Comment: ok I posted the update, I think this is going to come down to a maven dependency issue.

Answer (score 8):

You're using Spring 3.2.5, and it's not compatible with the latest Hibernate 4.3.3 version that you're using. Hibernate 4.3 indeed decided to change the package of the `ConnectionProvider` returned by `SessionFactoryImplementor.getConnectionProvider()`. Use the latest Spring version, or use Hibernate 4.2, and it should run better.

Comment: I switched my spring version to 4.0.2.RELEASE and hibernate-core to 4.2.0.Final, my app context loads now but I am back to the original exception message.

Comment: Try removing the property hibernate.current_session_context_class.